# Where is the entity in code field? [Display suite module]

Tags: display-suite, input-formats

I create a code field in Display Suite module and I need to insert a [`format_plural`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_plural/7) in it like

```
print format_plural([node:comment-count],  '1 Comment',  '@count Comments');
```

but token do not work in php block so I tryed:

```
dsm($node);
dsm($entity);
dsm($object);
```

but they do not work because 'Undefined variable' error.
Where is the node variable in display suite code field?

How can I achieve this output?

There is the screenshots
[image: field]
[image: error]

Comment: There's no implicit reason that you'd have access to the entity object within the PHP filter, it depends on what the caller has put into scope for you. `dpm(get_defined_vars());` should tell you what's available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED!

I needed to enable 'Display Suite Format' module.
If enable it give me a new text format 'Display Suite code' which give an $entity variable inside a code field!